# jquery plugin to change HTML checkbox style ！

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

Just like the stackoverflow style’s  input tag 
I found a jquery plugin to do that！
But I forget the name
Plz help！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [TagIt](http://webspirited.com/tagit/?page=tagit) plugin. However, it's not related to checkboxes at all.